# Pandoc not converting tables properly

Tags: pandoc

Using pandoc, I'm trying to convert a file from markdown format to PDF, it doesn't seem to be translating the tables properly. For example, I have the following in the markdown file:

```
><table>
> <tr>
>   <th>Name</th>
>   <th>Type</th>
>   <th>Description</th>
>   <th>Example</th>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td><strong>an-integer</strong></td>
>   <td><em>Integer</em></td>
>   <td>A 64-bit Number</td>
>   <td><code>"12346"</code></td>
> </tr>
></table>
```

I'm using the tool as follows:

pandoc -f markdown -o schema.pdf schema.md --latex-engine=/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex --toc --base-header-level=1 -s -S

What am I missing?

Comment: I suspect that StackOverflow's Markdown conversion is converting your example Markdown, such that we can't easily understand what it looks like. I think you probably want to treat your Markdown as a code block, so it appears as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Pandoc has a few different approaches to [table syntax](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#tables), but your code matches none of them. Try for example:

```
Name             Type         Description        Example
----             ----         -----------        -------
**an-integer**   *Integer*    A 64-bit Number    `12346`
```

Comment: Thanks! let me try that.